# 3 wire outlet.i know white goes with silver and black with copper. Does the order they go matter?

Tags: receptacle

[image][image]
There's six wires plus a ground. Wich one goes where?1234?‍♂️

Comment: Why do you have black tape on one white wire and one black wire? Black tape on a white wire means it is a hot. I think your whites are all neutrals. If the tape is because the wire has been stripped too long, then remove the tape and cut off a small bit at the end.

Comment: Look this is what happen I wanted to replace the outlet and forgot wich one came from which whole. And I wanted to test for power and accidently touched both black screws and screwed it all up now that room has no power whatsoever what can I do?

Comment: If the room has no power, disconnect all the wires that you've been fooling with, place wire nuts on the exposed ends, and reset the circuit breaker. Let us know if power is restored to the room.

Comment: No power has been restored.

Comment: If the power coming straight from the panel is one of these three cables then you won't have power to the rest of the room until everything is back together, which is one reason to use pigtails rather than screws+backstabs.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pigtail

You have 3 sets of wires in cables. One comes from the main panel (or from a previous device in the circuit). The others go to 2 other locations. But they are all effectively the same.

As far as I can tell, the old setup (and what you are trying to do now) includes two wires on a single screw. **You can't do that.** Or alternatively, one set of wires in backstabs and the others on screws, **which is legal but not recommended**. Instead, use pigtails:

- Connect all 3 blacks together with a wire nut and an additional short length of black wire. Connect the pigtail to the top brass screw.
- Connect all 3 whites together with a wire nut and an additional short length of white wire. Connect the pigtail to the top silver screw.

If you don't have any extra wire around to use for pigtails, get some. You may want to get Romex, aka NM, aka cable. In any case, you must make sure the wire is the same size or larger than the existing wire. That means using either 12 AWG (which will work for 15A or 20A circuits) or, if you are sure the circuit is a 15A circuit, 14 AWG.

In addition to avoiding the backstabs, using pigtails will allow this receptacle to be removed (provided you cap the pigtails with wire nuts) and still have the other devices on the circuit function properly.

Comment: I wire nut them together like you said and still no power

Comment: Do you have a non-contact tester to check individual wires? Or just the magic 8-ball tester shown in the picture? Any possibility there is another receptacle between the breaker and this one that might have a loose wire or bad backstab connection?

Comment: So just check every outlet? But none have any power

Comment: Are you sure have identified the correct breaker?

Answer (score 1):

Take all the whites wire nut them add a pigtail put on silver screw. Do the same with the blacks. Stay away from back stabbing wires into outlets. It does not mater how you hook on really. But I was taught at school to hook ground first then neutral then hots.Teach said that way ground path to panel in case someone turns on breaker. And I just do it that way. and always do. You need to get wire nut on grounds or a green one with a whole wire wire run out as pigtail or add one and ground to switch.

Answer (score 0):

The black wires (hots) go on the side with the shorter slot. The white wires (neutrals) go on the side with the longer slot.

Comment: I know the hot goes on the right but does it matter if it's on top or on the bottom

Comment: The order on the side does not matter. As people have said above it is better to connect the three whites together with a short length of white wire (aka a pigtail) and connect that to the receptacle, and same with black, but you must use a proper wire nut and proper wire for pigtails. It will work and is allowed by code to connect the wires individually to the back of the receptacle.

Comment: Thanks to all you people who answered me and I wish you a very happy father day to you all I couldn't done it with out you all thank you very much peace out!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The problem was another outlet since I made one spark the older ones  gave up

Comment: It looks like the white wires got hot on the ends. Is that burned insulation? That would mean that the back-wiring was not making good contact and heated up. The spring loaded back-wiring is notorious for failure. There is another type of back-wiring that is secured by screw clamp and is OK, but it looks like you have the spring loaded type. If you have that you should use the side screws. I would put two wires under one screw before I would use the spring loaded back-wire. Pigtails with proper wire nuts are better if you have the experience making them.

Comment: @JimStewart is absolutely right. While the receptacle *might* actually be OK if you move the wires from backstab to screws, I would put in a new receptacle (worth the $2 for peace of mind) and connect the wires using pigtails.